# Как сохранить кадр из видео ffmpeg?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Подскажите как сохранить кадр из видео?, вот например есть такой код

```
$file = "test.mp4";
$frame = 1;
$movie = new ffmpeg_movie($file);
$image = $movie->getFrame($frame);
$show_img = $image->toGDImage();
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($show_img);
imagedestroy($show_img);
```

Нужно чтобы этот кадр сохранялся на сервер

Comment: И в чём именно проблема сохранения GDI изображения на диск сервера используя [imagejpeg](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagejpeg.php)?

Comment: Нужен пример, чтобы изображение загружалось на сервер/сайт

Comment: У вас уже есть код который можно запустить на сервере, вы уж определитесь что именно вам нужно.

Comment: Может не так выразился, данный код выводит картинку, нужно чтобы эта картинка сохранялась на сервер например в корневую директорию, автоматически при переходе на нее

Comment: Смотрите документацию imagejpeg по ссылке, там есть что вам нужно.